# Programmatically get cast and output Types of operator

Tags: c#, reflection, casting

In C#, given two input `Type`s, it it possible to determine the output `Type` and implicit upcast `Type`s for an operator? For example, consider the expression `s + i`. Say I have the following information:

```
short s;
int i;
Type leftType = typeof(short);
Type rightType = typeof(int);
```

Can I determine the following information about the expression `s + i`?

```
Type leftUpcastType = typeof(int);
Type rightUpcastType = typeof(int);
Type outputType = typeof(int);
```

I obviously could do this with an enormous lookup table of all the types and operators, but there might be an easier way. Ideally this would work for user-defined classes with operator overloads too, but that is a secondary requirement.

Comment: See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691326(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: This is complicated: some operators are provided in IL by the compiler; some are custom `static` operators; then you've got implicit type conversions, lifted operators, etc... this is not simple!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve this using the `dynamic` Type.  Keep in mind, though, that dynamic will throw an exception for anything that can't be summed at *runtime* so you will need to ensure that you are only passing valid values or wrap in a try/catch.

```
var leftType = left.GetType();
var rightType = right.GetType();
var outputType = ((dynamic)left + (dynamic)right).GetType();
```

You can then infer from this information whether one, both or neither of the objects were converted for the operation.

Comment: This is one way to do it, but it should be kept in mind that you need to a) have types that support addition to each other, and b) have *values* that can be added together (some operands can cause exceptions). E.g. if you were trying this out with division and the right value was the integer 0, you'd get an exception, even if both types are compatible for addition and the return type is discernable.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this is to examine the return type of an expression that adds two values of the types you're interested in. This way you don't need to worry about providing valid *values* for the addition at runtime, when all you care about is the return *type*.

You can either take an existing expression and walk down the expression tree if one is available to you, or do something like this:

```
static Type GetTypeOfSummation<T1, T2>()
{
    var p1 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T1), "t1");
    var p2 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T2), "t2");

    LambdaExpression x = DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(new[] { p1, p2 }, null, "t1 + t2");
    return x.Body.Type;
}

static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(GetTypeOfSummation<int, double>());   // System.Double
    Console.WriteLine(GetTypeOfSummation<int, decimal>());  // System.Decimal
    Console.WriteLine(GetTypeOfSummation<float, double>()); // System.Double
}
```

This generic method will return the type of the addition operation without actually performing the addition.

You can of course do this with `Type` instances instead of generic type parameters as well, if that's what you want:

```
static Type GetTypeOfSummation(Type t1, Type t2)
{
    var p1 = Expression.Parameter(t1, "t1");
    var p2 = Expression.Parameter(t2, "t2");

    LambdaExpression x = DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(new[] { p1, p2 }, null, "t1 + t2");
    return x.Body.Type;
}
```

To be clear, `DynamicExpression` is from the `System.Linq.Dynamic` namespace, which you can obtain by referencing: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic/